# Excel indent not working with protected sheet

Tags: excel

I created an elaborate Excel file for work and then added protection to it. After allowing cell formatting whilst protected, I noticed that I could not indent or outdent text in a cell using the toolbar button. However, I could indent and outdent using the format dialog (right-click > format).

To recreate:

1. Create new Excel file (O365 latest Excel version)
2. Add text in cell A1
3. Protect sheet and allow Cell Format
4. Try to indent or outdent using toolbar button under Home > Alignment, for me this does not work
5. Right-click cell and select "Format Cells..." then indent text under Alignment tab using arrows, for me this works.

Anyone know if there is a fix for this? Or is this a bug/limitation?

Comment: Seems like a bug in Excel's ribbon Alignment menu.